# HTML Canvas pixel data type

Tags: javascript, html

I am using HTML5 and Javascript to get the mouse position and mouse movement as pixels from a canvas. With this style, is it possible to get the pixel data type as double data type? Because it looks like the pixel data is always returned as an integer data type.

I am asking because I have a backend system that is expected to process the pixel data as a double datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery  e.pageX and  e.pageY Property, they are numbers.
All numbers in JavaScript are doubles: that is, they are stored as 64-bit IEEE-754 doubles.

Comment: thanks Fatima for the suggestion. Just tried with JQuery. But it kind of just resolves the pixel position to an int data type.